# CENTOS 7 - Auto block IP with null routes

Tags: centos, iptables, ddos, route, netstat

Whenever I notice overload on my media (videos) server, I check for ddos with this command from netstat:

```
netstat -ntu | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

It shows currently established connection number by IP.

Basically, for my server conn. number between 1-20 is OK. But very often I get IPs with over 200 connections. It means someone is downloading tons of videos from my server. What I do is just `route add 0.0.0.0 reject`

I have to check and block IPs manually. Is there a way I could setup it to be automatic? Automatically route any IP that reaches conn. number of ~80.

Comment: Why don't you just configure your web server to rate-limit them?

Comment: It is configured with nginx rate-limiting.